# Can't install Magento due to permissions, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: magento, permissions, installation, chmod

I've run the following commands on my Magento directory on Ubuntu Server.

```
chmod 0777 var/.htaccess
chmod 0777 var
chmod 0777 app/etc
chmod -R 0777 media
```

However, now the Magento installer is still complaining with:

```
Path "/var/www/store/var/package" must be writable.
```

I tried:

```
chmod 0777 var/package
```

With no luck.

I've also tried [this guide for resetting permissions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions), still without any luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set permissions recursively:

`chmod -R 0777 var`